# Encode contact info (MeCard) on Android using ZXing

Tags: java, android, qr-code, android-contacts, zxing

I need to create QR code from contact info which is in [MeCard](http://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/imode/make/content/barcode/function/application/addressbook/index.html) format. I need to encode the following field:

- Name (N:)
- Url (URL:)
- Note (NOTE:)

I can correctly create all 3 fields using [ZXing QR Code Generator](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) (here is the [generated QR code](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chl=MECARD:N:name1;URL:http://www;NOTE:xyz;;) from the example below). However it doesn't work with ZXing app on Android Emulator. I'm using this snippet:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME, "name1");
data.putString("url", "http://www");
//data.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, "http://www");
data.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.NOTES, "xyz");
i.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "CONTACT_TYPE");
i.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", data);
startActivity(i);
```

The result: ZXing app only encode the `name` field.

[image]

**1.) How can I solve this issue?** Hopefully without dumping everything in name field.

**2.) Are there any alternative library support encoding?** ZXing seem to be the most popular.

Comment: Note: you can now encode the URL and NOTE field using `URL_KEY` and `NOTE_KEY` respectively as a key for the extra in the intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, it's that the Intent does not support a note or URL.

Comment: You are welcome to supply a patch! It's open source. http://code.google.com/p/zxing

Answer (score -1):

it's possible to encode url.
just use:
data.putString("email","http://www.xyz.com");